# Using Regular Expression remove HTML comments from content

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I am getting page contents into variable **$content**

I need to strip HTML comments from $content using regular expression. I tried following code, it's not working properly

```
$content = preg_replace('/<!--(.|\)*?-->/', '', $content);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

looks like you are missing something.

```
 $content = preg_replace( '/<!--(.|\s)*?-->/' , '' , $content );
```

You can test it here http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/1LX

Comment: You solution worked as expected. Thanks.

Comment: Any idea why this line of code is causing a "500 Internal Server Error" on my end?

Comment: This worked for me: $html = preg_replace("~<!--(.*?)-->~s", "", $html);

Comment: It is a very poor, resource-consuming pattern that [**will fail with longer input**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36885622/php-how-to-set-the-preg-groups-to-non-capture).

Answer (score 4):

Your back slash is escaping your `)`... I'm not sure what you think `(.|\)` is doing; Why not just use `.*?` and remove the capture group entirely?

Also, you want to set the `s` modifier to make `.` match new lines.

#### Revised code

```
$content = preg_replace('/<!--.*?-->/s', '', $content);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php
http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

you have to escape `!` because it's part of reg exp and also need to include new lines `s` modifier, this for if comment is not one line. And lazy flag `U` to match as less as possible, this when you got multiple comments 
Works perfect

```
$content = preg_replace('/<\!--.*-->/Us', '', $content);
```

Comment: The `!` does **not** need to be escaped... While the `U` modifier is an alternative the OP has already set the regex to match in an _ungreedy_ fashion with the use of `?`?

Comment: I said it for my own code