# Extraxt nonHTML tags with regular expression in PHP

Tags: php, html, regex, html-parsing

I'm trying to extract nonHTML tags ( like: `<!This TAG>` ) from strings.
I use below regular expression to extract tags:

```
$Tags = preg_split('/(<![^>]*[^\/]>)/i', $Content, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
```

But problem is all HTML comment tags ( like `<!-- This One -->` ) will be extract as well.

I can use a trick like below example to remove comment Tags but still any nonHTML tags between them will be extracted!

```
foreach($Tags as $key => $value) {
    if(mb_substr($value, 0, 4) == '<!--')
        continue;
    $CheckTag = mb_substr($value, 0, 2);
    if($CheckTag == '<!') {
        //...
    }
}
```

For examples:

`<!--<p>some text here.</p>-->` => Work.

`<!-- <!Tag1><!Tag2><!Tag3> -->` => Not Work! (Tag2 & Tags3 extracted)

I'm looking for better regular expression to skip entire content between `<!--` to `-->` , thanx for any tips.

For a better perspective this is the original function:

```
public function extractFakeTags($Content) {
        $Tags = preg_split('/(<![^>]*[^\/]>)/i', $Content, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
        $FakeTags = array();
        $Content = $Tags;
        foreach($Tags as $key => $current) {
            if(mb_substr($current, 0, 4) == '<!--')
                continue;
            $TagBegin = mb_substr($current, 0, 2);
            if($TagBegin == '<!') {
                $TagLength = mb_strlen($current);
                $TagEnd = mb_substr($current, ($TagLength-1), 1);
                if($TagEnd=='>') {
                    $TagName = mb_substr($current, 2, ($TagLength-3));
                    if (array_key_exists($TagName, $FakeTags)) {
                        array_push($FakeTags[$TagName], $key);
                    }
                    else {
                        $FakeTags[$TagName] = array($key);
                    }
                    $Content[$key] = NULL;
                }
            }
        }
        return $FakeTags;
    }
```

Comment: mistake #1: using a regex. you should be using [DOM](http://php.net/dom). Though, since you're dealing with non-html "tags", then probably htmlpurifier would be a better choice.

Comment: This code is a part of an HTML parser engine and i don't want to use any third-party class for some security reasons.
DOM is not an optimal way to parse many big strings. (Process time issue)

Comment: What security reasons (out of curiosity)?

Comment: Any intangible or unwanted possible bugs! Or any possible problem in their further updates!
This simple code work for me so far; but i'm not expert in regex. so a simple change in this regex could solve my problem instead of putting myself in another bigger problem!

Comment: The purpose of this code is to split a custom HTML Template to an array, for example:
`<div><!tag1><div>` 
to
`[0] => '<div>',
[tag1] => NULL,
[2] => '</div>
`

Comment: I founded a solution:
First remove any comments with this regex:
`<!--(.|\s)*?-->`
Then extract nonHTML tags with:
`(<![^>]*[^\/]>)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm looking for better regular expression to skip entire content between `<!--` to `-->`

To skip something use [(*SKIP)(*F)](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Special-Backtracking-Control-Verbs). Put such as `<!--(?s:.*?)-->(*SKIP)(*F)|` before:

```
/<!--(?s:.*?)-->(*SKIP)(*F)|(<![^>]*[^\/]>)/i
```

Didn't modify your actual regex. [Regex101 is good for testing](https://regex101.com/r/pZ9mE0/1) also see [Regex FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean/22944075#22944075) :)

Comment: Is it is better solution to skip comments:
`<!--(.|\s)*?-->(*SKIP)(*F)|(<![^>]*[^\/]>)`

according to [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19676024/using-regular-expression-remove-html-comments-from-content)

Comment: @DarkMaze Used the `s` [flag](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) ...`(?s:`... to make the dot also match newlines. Here it's the same like adding `s` at the end ...`/is` and change first part to `<!--.*?-->(*SKIP)(*F)`

Comment: @DarkMaze All these variants do the same: Maching as few as possibly of any character (also newline) between `<!--` and `-->` without capturing. 1.) `/<!--(?:.|\s)*?-->/` 2.) `/<!--(?s:.*?)-->/` 3.) `/<!--(?:(?s).*?)-->/` 4.) `/<!--.*?-->/s` 5.) `/<!--.*-->/Us` 6.) `/<!--[\s\S]*?-->/` just different notations. Yours needs a bit more steps possibly because of the alternation.