# PHP How to set the preg-groups to "non-capture" (?:...)

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, capturing-group, regex-group

In HTML page, I remove HTML comments like this

```
$contentHTML = preg_replace("#(?=<!--)([\s\S]*?)-->#", "", $contentHTML);
```

But on a huge page for `preg_replace`, I got "*PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size ...*"

Perhaps, one solution, would use the non-matching group to avoid capturing text?
Could someone explain how use on-matching group `?:`

Or how can I suppress HTML comments in huge page without `preg_replace`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just unroll the regex as

```
$contentHTML = preg_replace("#<!--[^-]*(?:-(?!->)[^-]*)*-->#", "", $contentHTML);
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xV1iJ0/1). Comapre with [yours](https://regex101.com/r/hG5jP2/1) taking about 3 times as more steps as mine with a very short example.

Details:

- `<!--` - start of comment
- `[^-]*` - 0+ non-`-`
- `(?:-(?!->)[^-]*)*`  - 0+ sequences of `-` that is not followed with `->` and then 0+ non-`-`s
- `-->` - comment end